# Detecting JavaScript on an HTML page using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, security

I'm currently working on a network security project that checks for XSS vulnerabilities on a website, which hopefully can be used for pen-testers out there (in case you don't believe me and think I'm some kinda script kiddy, here's the class website: http://netsec.cs.northwestern.edu/projects/).

So, I'm having trouble detecting JavaScript on a given HTML page. I spent many hours installing PyV8 and V8 and it seems that they can evaluate simple JavaScript statements. However, for more 'complex' JavaScript problems, for example, an alert box, PyV8 does not seem to support it. So, I doubt if I can feed PyV8 some arbitrary JavaScript code and expect it to give me the corresponding JavaScript output.

I did find this JS server/client in DrEval but it doesn't seem to work in the latest revision of V8/PyV8.

Please help! My project is due in about a week from today and no one in the class seems to be able to help me because this is a rather strange problem..

Uhmm.. And I apologize in advance if this question has been answered somewhere else before. I did search for this topic for at least 2 hours..

Thanks in advance for the responses!

Comment: Why aren't you trying to parse the HTML and looking for script tags or javascript function calls? It seems like that's the obvious way to detect whether JS is being used on a given page.

Comment: Nathon: Well this is really tricky. XSS attacks can come in lots of different forms. Checking for <script> tags is one way to do it, but I will need to check for encoded characters as well. So, I am currently leaning towards an interpreter approach since the regexes could get pretty disgusting if I did use the parsing approach.

Comment: You don't parse html with a regex.  You use a html parser. Also, link you provided doesn't load for me?  Lastly, how much time was given for this project?

Comment: @Chris: Pardon my poor tech vocabulary. Yup I guess you can use a parser but it goes back to the same problem: how do you deal with encoded characters efficiently? Idk why the link doesn't load, I sent an email to the TA; so it should be back up soon. I had a month for this project which I have spent working on other aspects (getting links/input fields/integrating with some given python framework) of the project. Why do you ask btw?

Comment: Curious about the project thats all.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

A incredibly hacky way would be to look for "text/javascript" in the source of the webpage.

```
import urllib2
if urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.co.uk').read().find('text/javascript') == 0:
    print "It has js."
```

This is NOT the best answer I would be happy to hear from someone who does know the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do but here are some thoughts:

1. If you want to run JavaScript code in the context of a web page, you need a browser or an emulation of one. Try [envjs](http://www.envjs.com/). It needs Java, though, because it needs a JavaScript interpreter.

   I'm not aware of a library which offers the same functionality for Python. Maybe you can fix that. envjs is written mostly in JavaScript but it needs some support functions from the interpreter (printing to the console, downloading data, opening files).
2. XSS vulnerabilities happen if you can inject JavaScript code into a page, no matter what code already exists. So you need to check all fields of a form, post the form to the server and then check that it properly escapes all values on the next page.

Comment: Hello Aaron, thanks for the response. I'm trying to attack my own (insecure) forum with XSS string injections using a python script. I'm able to perform the injections successfully but I don't really know how to read the javascript output from the page that I injected. For example, if I did an injection with an alert box, a human would see this alert box, but all my script sees is just some text from the HTTP response. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in python since that's what my project needs to be written in. I will continue to explore envjs in the meantime..

Comment: Well, if the rest of the page doesn't use `"alert('XSS')"`, then add this to your XSS attack and search for this exact string.

Comment: That approach definitely works for un-encoded XSS injections but what about encoded ones? For example, j <--> &#x6A; in html. So, you can build an encoded XSS attack which will show up normally on a browser but remain as encoded characters in the page source. This is why I would prefer to use a JS interpreter instead of using parsing/regexing.

Comment: That's not the point; the interpreter will execute anything it can find. The question is not "how is it encoded?" but "can I insert the code?" If all inputs are properly escaped, no encoding trick will make XSS work again. Say you try to hide the script with using `&#6A;`. If escaping works, that becomes `&amp;#6A;` -> dead

Answer (score 0):

PyV8 is Python binding of V8 javascript engine. It can evaluate even the most complex javascript code. It is also being used by Google Chrome.

That being said, there are a few things you need to do to make it work properly. First of all, PyV8 is a **javascript engine only**. It does not construct the DOM. Thus, you need to create a DOM yourself and run the PyV8 context with it.

Also, you have said that the alert function does not work. The `alert();` function is part of the DOM, it is shorthand of `window.alert();`. So, you have to specify each function and property in DOM.

PyV8 source comes with a simple DOM. You can download it from http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/source/browse/